# How to access context inside Yup schema

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup, react-hook-form

I'm using `react-hook-form` with `Yup` library for managing my forms in my app.

I'm trying to create dynamic Yup schema According to my component state.

For example:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { FirstFormContext } from "../context/FirstFormContext";
import { SecondFormContext } from "../context/SecondFormContext";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import * as yup from "yup";

const schema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup.string().email().min(2), // <-- Here I want to access the value
  address: yup.string().min(2).max(20)
});

const SecondForm = () => {
  const { secondFormData, setSecondFormData } = useContext(SecondFormContext);
  const { firstFormData } = useContext(FirstFormContext);
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    context: firstFormData.type // <---- Passing the variable
  });
  const history = useHistory();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    setSecondFormData(data);
    history.push("/end-page");
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <button
        style={{ display: "block", marginBottom: "20px" }}
        onClick={() => history.push("/")}
      >
        Go back
      </button>
      {firstFormData.type === "one" ? (
        <input
          defaultValue={secondFormData.email}
          placeholder="email"
          {...register("email", { required: true })}
        />
      ) : firstFormData.type === "two" ? (
        <input
          defaultValue={secondFormData.address}
          placeholder="address"
          {...register("address", { required: true })}
        />
      ) : null}

      <button type="submit" style={{ display: "block", marginTop: "20px" }}>
        Next
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default SecondForm;
```

As you can see, inside my component I'm passing the context to `useForm` hook and I want to access it in the Yup schema above the `SecondForm` component.

How can I achieve it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 26):

I solved it that way:

**Inside `useForm` hook**

```
const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    context: { type: firstFormData.type }
  });
```

**In my `schema` :**

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup
    .string()
    .email()
    .min(2)
    .when("$type", (type, schema) => {
      console.log(type);
      if (type === "one") {
        return schema.required();
      }
      return;
    }),
  address: yup.string().min(2).max(20)
});
```

Comment: Just what I needed - thank you

Comment: Hi. What if there is more than one context variable and we wanted to access them all inside a single ```.when()``` function?

Comment: @Arad, you will then use an array as first parameter to the when function: